# Insert Pagebreak for Output after Code Chunk

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, page-break

I have a .Rmd file which I am converting to PDF. For layout reasons, I want to display the generated output plot of my code chunk on the next page even though it would just fit in underneath.

Normally with text etc. one would use

```
\pagebreak
```

But how can I signalize the code chunk that it should display its output on the next page?
Thanks for helping!

Comment: Try  with  `\newpage`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a `knitr` hook to set up a chunk option to do this.

So here I have modified the source chunk hook and created a chunk option `next_page` which, if `TRUE`, the output of that chunk will be on the next page.

````
---
title: "Chunk Output in Next page"
output: pdf_document
date: "2022-11-25"
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

```{r, include=FALSE}
library(knitr)

default_source_hook <- knit_hooks$get('source')

knit_hooks$set(
  source = function(x, options) {
    if(isTRUE(options$next_page)) {
      paste0(default_source_hook(x, options),
        "\n\n\\newpage\n\n")
    } else {
      default_source_hook(x, options)
    }
  }
)
```

```{r, next_page=TRUE}
plot(mpg ~ disp, data = mtcars)
```
````

---

[image: chunk output in the next page]

---

Comment: BTW. the plot hook could be more direct but I like your solution is general so will work with any output/plot.

Comment: Great solution but please consider to edit the function to  `source = function(x, options) {     if(isTRUE(options$next_page)) {       paste0(default_source_hook(x, options), "\n\n\\newpage\n\n")     } else {       default_source_hook(x, options)     }   }` and change the argument to take logical TRUE/FALSE and It will look much better in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to save the output in the file (png/jpeg/pdf) and then load it with the markdown or `knitr`.
Such solution gives you a full control.

### Automatic

I found alternative solution in [rmarkdown-cookbook](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/fig-chunk.html).

We generate a plot in this code chunk but do not show it:

````
```{r cars-plot, dev='png', fig.show='hide'}
plot(cars)
```

\newpage

![A nice plot.](\`r knitr::fig_chunk('cars-plot', 'png')\`)
````

### Manual

````
```{r}
png("NAME.png") 
# your code to generate plot 
dev.off()
```
````

then load image with

`![LABEL](PATH/NAME.png)` or with

````
```{r echo=FALSE, out.width='100%', ...}
knitr::include_graphics('PATH/NAME.png')
```
````

Comment: @shafee thanks for the edit I did not know the ~~~ trick:) I have to check if it works on github too:D

Comment: It works on github too, it is a game changer for me:D thanks @shafee

Comment: You can also render three backtick (`) sign by wrapping them with four backtick sign, but I find using tilde (~) more easier.